# Issue posting file using ixudra CURL in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, curl

Having an issue with posting files using ixudra/curl, it is constantly feeding back that the file cannot be found.

```
Curl::to('https://website.co.uk/path')
    ->withFile( 'filename', 'file:///home/forge/website/public/uploads/csv/ngrjJAgPOv.csv', 'text/csv', 'filename.csv' )
    ->post();
```

The response that I am getting back is;

```
{#601 ▼
  +"content": false
  +"status": 0
  +"contentType": null
  +"error": "couldn't open file "file:///home/forge/website/public/uploads/csv/ngrjJAgPOv.csv""
}
```

I have tried with a relative path of both `/public/uploads/csv/ngrjJAgPOv.csv` and `/uploads/csv/ngrjJAgPOv.csv` but to no avail.

If I manually go to the url the file is there, any ideas?

Comment: Permission issue (try `chmod 0777 <file_path>` to confirm or not this possibility) ? 
The error come from your code or is it the response from the distant server ?